# Could you explain how to generate pincode in android code

Tags: nest-api

I'm struggling to generate pincode in source code. Actually I can't even guess how to do that.
I'v already read nest doc about how to make pincode.
I understood that just copy url with client id and secret. And paste it to the address bar.
If a user accept that, we can achieve the pincode. 
Is it true that user find the pincode at the first prior to develper?
If I have lots of user, how can they(users) confirm pincode one by one? even though user exists only one. I think, they aren't interested in that code. Pincode is necessary for only develper.

Could you explain how to make pincode in source code?
Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIN codes are indeed one per user, you are asking your user for access to their Nest account.

Flow is generally:

1. User logs into your app/account
2. User click your pair with Nest button and you load the Auth URL in a WebView
3. User logs into their Nest account and grants permissions
4. Either a PIN code, or a redirect with access code is returned (configurable by you)
5. Your app sends access code, secret, and client ID to Nest to get an access token, which you store like a password and use to access the Nest API on behalf of the user.

The Android Sample code from Nest includes the authorization flow, and is likely what you want: https://github.com/nestlabs/android-NestDK/blob/master/NestLib/src/main/java/com/nestapi/lib/UserAuthActivity.java

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your commment. It helps me to solve my question. Thank you.